# Is Azure Cloud Service Worker role the only Azure hosting option for running an EventHub EventProcessor?

Tags: signalr, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-hub, event-processor-host

I'm currently fighting my way through Event Hubs and EventProcessorHost. All guidance I found so far suggests running an EventProcessor in an Azure Cloud Service worker role. Since those are very slow to deploy and update I was wondering if there is any Azure service that lets me run an EventProcessor in a more agile environment?

So far my rough architecture looks like this

Device > IoT Hub > Stream Analytics Job > Event Hub > [MyEventProcessor] > SignalR > Clients...

Or maybe there is another way of getting from Steam Analytics to fire SignalR messages?

Any recommendations are highly appreciated.

Thanks, Philipp

Comment: Could you share the recommendation of cloud service? For now, i do not see the sense to add the Cloud Service as the extra-step between EH and SignalR.

Answer (score 1):

You may use Azure Web App service with the SignalR enabled and merge your pipeline "steps" [MyEventProcessor] and SignalR into one step. 
I have done that a few times, started from the simple SignalR chat demo and added the Event Hub receiver functionality to the SignalR processing. [That](http://www.mikelanzetta.com/2015/08/real-time-mapping-with-signalr-and-event-hubs/) article is close to what i mean in terms of approach.

You may take a look at Azure WebJobs as well. Basically, it can work as a background service doing your logic. [WebJobs SDK has the support of Event Hub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/EventHub-support).

Comment: Hi Alex, that sounds promising. I was under the impression the EventProcessor would need to be hosted in a somewhat of always running task. One of the sources I used so far is this one https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2015/02/24/scaling-azure-event-hubs-processing-with-worker-roles/

Comment: @PhilippBauknecht if you need something more like-background-service, then take a look at Azure WebJobs. Basically, it can work as a background service doing your logic. WebJobs SDK has the support of Event Hub. https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/EventHub-support

Answer (score 0):

You can run an EventProcessorHost in any Azure thing that will run arbitrary C# code and will keep running. The options for where you *should* run it end up depending on how much you want to spend and what you need. So [Azure Container Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/container-service/) may be the new fancy deployment system, but it's minimum cost may not be suitable for you. I'm running my binaries that read data from EventHubs on normal Azure Virtual Machines with our deployment system in charge of managing them.

If your front end processes using SignalR to talk to clients have a process that stays around for a while, you could just make each one of those their own logical consumer (consumer group) and have them consume the entire stream. Or even if they don't stay around (ie you're using an Azure hosting option that turns off the process when idle) you could write your receiver to just start at the end of stream (as opposed to reprocessing older data), if that's what your scenario requires.